Adding Constraints to Linear Programming Problem in PuLP
Question:
I am working on a linear programming problem using pulp in Python to model power generation constraints for multiple generators. I need to ensure the solution meets the following criteria:

Demand Satisfaction: The total power generated at each time step should meet or exceed the demand.
Ramp-Up and Ramp-Down Constraints: The rate of change in power generation for each generator should adhere to specified ramp-up and ramp-down limits.
Absolute Difference Constraints: The absolute difference between power generation at consecutive time steps should be within specified limits.
Capacity Constraints: The power generated by each generator at any time should be within its minimum and maximum capacity.

code:
def add_constraints(prob, generators, power_vars, demand):
    
    abs_diff_vars = {}
    for gen in generators:
        name = gen["name"]
        for t in range(1, len(demand)):
            abs_diff_vars[(name, t)] = pulp.LpVariable(f"abs_diff_{name}_{t}", lowBound=0)

    # Demand Satisfaction Constraints
    for t in range(len(demand)):
        prob += pulp.lpSum([power_vars[(gen["name"], t)] for gen in generators]) >= demand[t], f"Demand_Satisfaction_{t}"

    # Ramp-Up and Ramp-Down Constraints
    for t in range(1, len(demand)):
        for gen in generators:
            name = gen["name"]
            rampup = gen["rampup"]
            rampdown = gen["rampdown"]

            # Ramp-up constraint
            prob += power_vars[(name, t)] - power_vars[(name, t-1)] <= rampup, f"Ramp_Up_Constraint_{name}_{t}"

            # Ramp-down constraint
            prob += power_vars[(name, t-1)] - power_vars[(name, t)] <= rampdown, f"Ramp_Down_Constraint_{name}_{t}"
        
            # Absolute Difference Constraints
            prob += abs_diff_vars[(name, t)] >= (power_vars[(name, t)] - power_vars[(name, t-1)]), f"Abs_Diff_Upper_{name}_{t}"
            prob += abs_diff_vars[(name, t)] >= (power_vars[(name, t-1)] - power_vars[(name, t)]), f"Abs_Diff_Lower_{name}_{t}"

    # Capacity Constraints
    for t in range(len(demand)):
        for gen in generators:
            name = gen["name"]
            max_power = gen["max"][t]
            min_power = gen["tech_min"][t]
            
            # Max Power Constraint
            prob += power_vars[(name, t)] <= max_power, f"Max_Power_{name}_{t}"

            # Min Power Constraint
            prob += power_vars[(name, t)] >= min_power, f"Min_Power_{name}_{t}"

Inputs:
Demand - 
[
  17116.3, 16940.71, 16948.98, 16839.5, 16808.51, 16800.25,
16782.69, 16768.23, 16762.03, 16559.6, 16566.83, 16583.35,
16357.16, 16340.63, 16342.7, 16121.67, 16250.77, 16479.03,
16721.75, 17053.29, 17425.12, 17859.95, 18199.75, 18375.34,
18425.95, 18440.4, 18453.83, 18461.06, 18764.72, 18746.13,
18648.01, 18786.41, 18678.99, 18636.65, 18827.72, 18818.43,
19127.25, 19337.95, 19317.29, 19294.57, 19243.96, 19224.33,
19229.5, 19254.29, 19225.37, 19146.87, 19002.27, 18857.67,
18675.89, 18712.04, 18732.7, 18582.94, 18465.19, 18114.03,
18125.39, 18194.59, 18249.33, 18276.18, 18274.12, 18015.91,
18042.76, 18089.24, 18456.93, 18492.05, 18510.64, 18197.69,
18192.52, 18191.49, 18193.56, 18255.53, 18317.5, 18548.85,
18781.24, 19061.14, 19222.27, 19378.23, 19523.86, 19711.84,
19824.42, 19614.75, 19239.83, 18839.08, 18714.11, 18619.09,
18526.13, 18373.27, 18215.24, 18119.19, 18089.24, 18076.84,
18007.64, 17849.62, 17693.66, 17604.83, 17572.82, 17579.01]

Generator - 
[
{
        "cn_unit_source": "INTER",
        "cn_dispatch_type": "MERIT",
        "variable_charges": 1.6921,
        "rampup": 40.0,
        "rampdown": 40.0,
        "tech_min": [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                     0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],
        "name": "KSTPS7_22799688",
        "max": [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    }, ]


This is unreadable.

So, what is the question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The constraints seem to be well implemented. However, in the data you provided, max=min=0, so the generation would naturally be 0 and the demand would not be fulfilled.
